# Ecto Associations

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework, ecto

So I'm creating a simple app where user can posts. I'm still learning elixir so please bear with me.

**MODEL SCHEMA**

- User
- Avatar
- Post
- Comment

My problem is associating the **user** in the **comment** schema.

**user** -> **has_one** -> **avatar**

**user** -> **has_many** -> **post** -> **has_many** -> **comments** (user?)

I'm confused on how will I associate the **user** to **comments**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Each schema is allowed to have multiple associations. So you will want something that looks similar to the following

**user**

- `has_one avatar`
- `has_many posts`
- `has_many comments`

**avatar**

- `belongs_to user`

**post**

- `belongs_to user`
- `has_many comments`

**comment**

- `belongs_to user`
- `belongs_to post`

I believe this should cover what you are looking for.